# Can you auto-populate a field in Survey123 from another field by only pulling certain characters?

Tags: algorithm, fields-attributes, function, regular-expression, arcgis-survey123

I have a field where the user inputs text Aa1Bb2Cc3

Am I able to auto populate another field by only populating the field with Bb or 3.

Auto populate the field with characters [4:6] or just [9]

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this. You can reference [Survey123 Formulas](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/create-surveys/xlsformformulas.htm)

and also the [Quick reference guide](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/create-surveys/quickreferencecreatesurveys.htm)

The functions below should allow you auto populate another field.

`Function   Description Example`
`selected(question, value)`

> Checks if answer is selected. Used for select_one and select_multiple questions

`selected(${question_one}, 'a')`

`count-selected(question)`

> Returns the number of selected answers. Used for select_multiple questions.

`count-selected(${question_one})`

`string-length(question)`

> Returns the length of a nonempty string.

`string-length(${question_one})`

`substr(question, start, end)`

> Returns the substring beginning at the specified start and extends to the character at index end -1, where start and end begin at 0.

`substr(${question_one},1 ,2)`